# Ubuntu kernel upgrade after graphic card driver update

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, upgrade, kernel

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with an ATI Radeon 5450 graphic card. I use 2 monitors, and I had to update the video driver because the default one doesn't remember its settings after reboot. I have found out that `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates` does the trick.

There are however some compatibility problems between the kernel and an application, so I am forced to upgrade it. The only problem is that after upgrading the kernel, Ubuntu does not start any more leaving me with an empty black screen.

Any ideas on how to upgrade the kernel after a video driver update? Reinstalling is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

check that you have `linux-headers-generic` installed, and simply update the whole system not only driver.